# Prove that this set of points is finite or countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R} $ be such that $|x-y| > 3 \ \  \forall x, y \in X, x \ne y$. Prove that $X$ is a finite or countable set.

Here, normally I would try to find a formula or any other reasonable way to build a bijection between the set and $\mathbb{N}$.

In this case, however, the approach when I tried to fix $y$ and then consider $x > y_0+3$ and $x < y_0 - 3$ and thus show that we can enumerate each set in the union with natural numbers resulted in a counter-intuitive conclusion.

How do I build the bijection in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider all intervals $[n,n+1]$ ($n\in\Bbb Z$). If $X$ was uncountable, at least one of those intervals would have more than one element of $X$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: But every two elements of $X$ are at least at a distance of 3 from each other, which means that there can't be more than one element in each interval so the set is countable. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

For each $n\in \Bbb Z$ there is at most one $x\in X\cap [n,n+3).$ So for $x\in X$ let $f(x)=n$ if $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $x\in [n,n+3).$ Then $f:X\to \Bbb Z$  is injective.